# How to change the product list 'desc' direction

Tags: magento2, product-list, magento2.2.3, magento2.2.4

How to change the product list 'desc' direction?

Now Old product is default.

I want to change is new product position is default > ?product_list_dir=desc

using `Magento Version 2.2.4`

thank you!

Comment: plz explain properly

Comment: want to change the date position : asc to desc <-- @MuhammadAhsanHorani

Answer (score 1):

You should add the below code **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is this,
edit the file located in:

```
..MAGENTO_DIR/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php
```

add this line:

```
$this->_direction = strtolower('desc'); //choose 'asc' or 'desc'
```

in this position:

```
    public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    $this->_direction = strtolower('desc'); // *** THIS POSITION ***

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'position') {
            $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
                $this->getCurrentOrder(),
                $this->getCurrentDirection()
            )->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', $this->getCurrentDirection());
        } else {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I hope I was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be overwriting the method ***prepareSortableFieldsByCategory*** of the class ***Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct***
and add the following code to the method

```
if (!$this->getDefaultDirection()) {
    $this->setDefaultDirection('desc');
}
```

Complete code:

```
    public function prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($category)
{
    if (!$this->getAvailableOrders()) {
        $this->setAvailableOrders($category->getAvailableSortByOptions());
    }
    $availableOrders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
    if (!$this->getSortBy()) {
        $categorySortBy = $this->getDefaultSortBy() ?: $category->getDefaultSortBy();
        if ($categorySortBy) {
            if (!$availableOrders) {
                $availableOrders = $this->_getConfig()->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
            }
            if (isset($availableOrders[$categorySortBy])) {
                $this->setSortBy($categorySortBy);
            }
        }
    }
    /***Change direction***/
    if (!$this->getDefaultDirection()) {
        $this->setDefaultDirection('desc');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Another solution could be using xml mentioned in the following post

Link: [Change product sorting from desc to asc on category page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320862/change-product-sorting-from-desc-to-asc-on-category-page)