# Change product sorting from desc to asc on category page

Tags: magento2, catalog, filter

When entering a category, I select the sorting type product name. Sorting shows products in desc mode (z-a) how to implement default asc mode (a-z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file in the theme along the path `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

Add there

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
                <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                    <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on this arrow your products get sorted a-z, this button reverse the sorting, Hope it will help you

[image]

Comment: I need this functionality by default asc